# Is there any freeware tool available to convert MS Excel files to MS Access DB files?

Tags: excel, ms-access

Is there any freeware tool available to convert MS Excel files to MS Access DB files that woks for both 2003 and 2007 formats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Access running on the computer you can open the spreadsheet in Access to create a new database from it, or use "Import Data" to import the Excel spreadsheets into tables. If it's a big deal, use Office Automation to speed the process up.

Otherwise, the Access Connectivity Engine (ACE) is an ODBC driver that can connect to both Access and Excel files. You could write something to transfer data between them. It's free but a bit of work.

Alternatively you could use SSIS, which is also free with SQL Server Express edition. But certainly a lot of overhead just to convert between files.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this right from Microsoft Access. Click `File > Open`, and set the filetype to `Microsoft Excel Workbook`, then open the worksheet.

A wizard will then appear to guide you through importing the workbook into a database. You can set which sheet to use for the database, which columns should be used, whether the data has headers, etc. This should work for any excel file.

Comment: Yes, I am able to open it but not being able to save it in mdb format.

Comment: Really? What happens when you try to save it as a database? It looks to me like it worked...

Comment: Did you understand the problem? An mdb file is created but it is linked with the Excel file. If I delete the Excel file, the mdb file is unable to load data. I need a standalone mbd file to work with.